# Can I programmatically create a coupon code from a link in an email?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, coupon

There are 10 coupons in a mail. When somebody wants to print one, they will click a link in the mail which will generate a unique, printable (PDF) coupon code for that person.

How to generate that coupon code - where will the script reside? Will there be a server listening to the clicks?

Comment: In order to solve this problem you need to learn quite a lot of things. It is not something you can solve by simply asking for directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in the email should go to your site.

Something like the following:
Email -> yoursite.com/coupon.php?generate=1

coupon.php will be the php script on your server generating the coupon. The coupon can either be pre-generated and displayed or generated on the spot.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to grab the email address of the email recipient?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can code it to the mailing script so that it's embedded in the link when its sent. eg. yoursite.com/coupon.php?generate=1&email=user@gmail.com